# can't capture dynamic environment in a fn item, but the code is already in a || {} closure

Tags: rust

I've stripped my problematic code down to this sample:

```
fn foo(input_vector: Vec<()>) {
    const bar: Option<()> = []
        .iter()
        .map(|_| { input_vector; })
        .nth(0);
}

fn main() {
    foo(vec![]);
}
```

Which yields the following error:

```
error[E0434]: can't capture dynamic environment in a fn item; use the || { ... } closure form instead
--> src/main.rs:4:20
  |
4 |         .map(|_| { input_vector; })
  |                    ^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

Why is the compiler telling me to use a closure if I'm already using one?

Comment: This is a terrible compiler error for this bug.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's an even shorter example that produces the same error:

```
fn foo(a: i32) {
    const b: i32 = a;
}
```

The issue is that `const` doesn't declare a local variable; it declares a global constant (though it can be scoped to a function or a block). Constants are meant to have the same value all the time, thus their value cannot depend on a parameter.

If you want an immutable local variable, use `let` instead.

Comment: *slaps forehead* I've been writing too much TypeScript and didn't even notice that. What is the use-case for being able to declare `const` in a non-global scope?

Comment: @stuffy so "it can be scoped to a function or a block". Why have something in a broader scope than you need it to be?

Comment: Okay, so it's strictly a visibility thing. In most languages I use defining a global is the same as defining a local, i.e., you would incur the cost of the assignment on every invocation if you tried to scope it like this. I see that Rust grants you finer control so you can have constants in narrower scopes but still only evaluate them once. Thanks!